# Proving Triangle inequality for $p \in (0, \infty)$ in space $l^p$

Tags: inequality

The triangle inequality holds for $(l^p, \Vert \cdot\Vert_p)$ for $p \in [1, \infty]$. However, for $p \in (1, \infty)$ is somewhat a difficult job to be done. Does any one have any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use \in for "is element of" in LaTeX, it looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: thank you for your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Minkowski inequality, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: That helped to a great extent. Thank you